# I can't understand of the RMS Scheduling proof

Tags: static, proof, rms

I'm Korean. Sorry to my awful English.

I was learned RMS Scheduling some days ago.
And, my professor explain these proof.

[For example, there are two tasks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOxFe.png)

[Proof](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5XkQJ.png)

The second page that is 'Proof' is what I can't understand.

What is the T_n and C_n.
And what is the meaning of [T2/T1] in the Case(1). ( Obviously, next step in Case(2) )

plz, explain it. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

A *periodic* task is a task that repeats its execution over and over again. Given a periodic task `t`  there are two quantities associated to it:

- It's *period*, denoted `T`
- It's *deadline*, denoted `C`

The period `T` measures the interval of time on which the task should be executed at least once. For instance, if `T` is `100 ms`, the task `t` has to be executed at least *once* every `100 ms`. This means that it has to be executed at least *twice* every `200 ms`, and so on. In other words, after `T` units of time (e.g., `ms`) there is a new deadline for `t` and the goal is to have the task completing a new execution before that deadline expires.

Quantity `C` measures the maximum execution time of the task. This means that at every instance of its execution the task is guaranteed to complete within `C` units of time. For the sake of simplicity you can think of `C` as the constant execution time; just keep in mind that in some cases the execution might complete sooner.

Note that it wouldn't be possible to honor these constraints if `C > T`. That's why it is assumed that `C < T`. In the example above, `C` should be smaller than `100 ms`, say `C = 40 ms`. The case `C = T` is not interesting either because you will only be able to re-execute `t` as soon as it completes without any time left for sharing the *processor* (e.g., the CPU) with other tasks.

The integer quotient `[T/C]` is the maximum number of times the task can be executed in a period. When this happens, the task will be using the processor a fraction `U = C/T` of its total processing time. In the example above, we have `[T/C] = [100/40] = 2` and you will be able to repeat `t` at most twice every period of length `T`, which will allocate `U = 40/100 = 0.4` or `40%` of the total processing time. The quantity `U` is called *utilization*.

With these descriptions you should now be able to go to any online introduction to RMS and make sense of it. For example, you might want to take a look at [this one](http://www.embedded.com/electronics-blogs/beginner-s-corner/4023927/Introduction-to-Rate-Monotonic-Scheduling).